# $watch vs. ngChange

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

Say that you want to do something when a property of `$scope` changes. And say that this property is bound to an `input` field. What are the advantages/disadvantages of using `$watch` vs. using `ngChange`?

**html**

```
<input ng-model="foo" ng-change="increment()">
<p>foo: {{foo}}</p>

<!-- I want to do something when foo changes.
     In this case keep track of the number of changes. -->
<p>fooChangeCount: {{fooChangeCount}}</p>
```

**js**

```
// Option 1: $watch
$scope.$watch('foo', function() {
  $scope.fooChangeCount++;
});

// Option 2: ngChange
$scope.fooChangeCount = 0;
$scope.increment = function() {
  $scope.fooChangeCount++;
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/4xJWpU6AN9HIp0OSZjgm?p=preview

I understand that there are times when you need to use `$watch` (if the value you're looking to watch isn't bound to an input field). And I understand that there are times when you need to use `ngChange` (when you want to do something in response to a change in an input, but not necessarily in response to a scope property change).

However, in this case both accomplish the same thing.

My thoughts:

- `ngChange` seems cleaner, and easier to understand what's happening.
- `$watch` seems like it might be slightly faster, but probably negligible. With `ngChange`, I think Angular would have to do some extra work in the compile phase to set up the event listeners, and perhaps extra event listeners decrease speed a bit. Regardless of whether or not you use `ngChange`, the digest cycle runs on changes, so you have an opportunity to listen for something and call a function in response to changes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Bottom line - You can achieve with $watch every thing you can achieve with ng-change but not vice-versa.

Purposes:

> **ngChange** - binded to a HTML element
>
> **$watch** - observing scope's model objects (HTML object models included)

My rule of thumb - if you can use ng-change use it to match your scenario, otherwise use $watch

Why you shouldnt use $watch?

1. It’s inefficient - Adding complexity to your $digest
2. It’s hard to test effectively
3. It's not clean

Comment: can we use ngOnChange component lifecycle hook instead of using $watch?

Answer (score 1):

You have it mostly right. `ng-change` is very DOM specific and for evaluating an expression when the change event fires on a DOM element.

`$watch` however, is a lower-level (and more general purpose) utility that watches your view model or `$scope`. So your watch function will fire every time the user types a key (in the example of an input).

So to contrast, one listens to DOM events, the other watches your data.

Answer (score 0):

$watch adds more complexity do the $digest, making it less efficient. In your case ngChange it's a cleaner and easier solution...

Font: http://www.benlesh.com/2013/10/title.html